# Navigation component with bottom navigation in android

Tags: java, android, components, android-bottomnavigationview

After splashing, my app enters an main activity where the navigation button has 4 tabs, but until the user has logged in, instead of the profile tab, he should see the login fragment, but after logging in, he can see the profile tab.
I save the token and check with a boolean if it is logged in or not but this is not true can anyone help
I use navigation component with bottom navigation.
Is ok write switch case in menu and check my boolean?

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kE7Ba.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSE4K.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_graf"
    app:startDestination="@+id/menu_store">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/menu_store"
        android:name="com.ostovane.android.view.fragments.BaseStoreFragment"
        android:label="@string/base_store"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_base_store" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:name="com.ostovane.android.view.fragments.SearchFragment"
        android:label="@string/search"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_search" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/menu_category"
        android:name="com.ostovane.android.view.fragments.CategoryFragment"
        android:label="@string/category"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_category" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/menu_my_products"
        android:name="com.ostovane.android.view.fragments.MyProductsFragment"
        android:label="@string/my_products"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_myproduct" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/menu_profile"
        android:name="com.ostovane.android.view.fragments.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="@string/profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_profile_dest_to_login_dest"
            app:destination="@id/authenticate"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/profile_dest"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/authenticate"
        android:name="com.ostovane.android.view.fragments.auth.UnAuthenticatedFragment"
        android:label="@string/authenticate"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_un_authenticated" />

</navigation>
```

some mainactivity

import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint;

@AndroidEntryPoint
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

```
private ActivityMainBinding binding;
private boolean isLogin = false;
private String authToken;


@Inject
ProfileFragment profileFragment;
@Inject
UnAuthenticatedFragment authenticatedFragment;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);


    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = binding.bottomNavigationBar;
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);


    NavInflater navInflater = navController.getNavInflater();
    NavGraph graph = navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.navigation_graf);

    if (!isLogin) {
        graph.setStartDestination(R.id.action_profile_dest_to_login_dest);
        navController.navigate(R.id.menu_profile);
    } else {
        graph.setStartDestination(R.id.menu_profile);
        navController.navigate(R.id.authenticate);

    }
}
```

}

@AndroidEntryPoint
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

```
private ActivityMainBinding binding;
private boolean isLogin = false;
private String authToken;


@Inject
ProfileFragment profileFragment;
@Inject
UnAuthenticatedFragment authenticatedFragment;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

    
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = binding.bottomNavigationBar;
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);


    NavInflater navInflater = navController.getNavInflater();
    NavGraph graph = navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.navigation_graf);

    if (!isLogin) {
        graph.setStartDestination(R.id.action_profile_dest_to_login_dest);
        navController.navigate(R.id.menu_profile);
    } else {
        graph.setStartDestination(R.id.menu_profile);
        navController.navigate(R.id.authenticate);

    }
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="toolbarViewModel"
        type="com.ostovane.android.viewmodel.ToolbarViewModel" />

</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_color"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/Widget.BottomNavigationView"
        app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/Widget.BottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu_item" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavigationBar"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_graf" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the code as text not images

Comment: As per the other question, what items display in your `BottomNavigationView` is controlled by that view's Menu, not by anything in Navigation, so you can hide/show menu items by using the `Menu` APIs.

Comment: added some code